# What this page means for the Debian's package version

Tags: debian, package-management, version

I am trying to figure out what these web page means for the version. I know that the epoch is the number previous the double dot. But I can't figure out what this all means ?

[image]

I found this [here](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/data/missing-epochs)

Answer (score 2):

As you noted, the epoch is the number in front of a colon, specifically used in Debian pacakges.

If the scheme of upstream package version changes or if there was an error 
with an upload, the epoch of a package can be increased to remain a consistent ordering of packages with different versions, which is e.g. important at any system update.

The page you found just lists the security reports with a wrong/missing epochs. This happens when the current epoch of a package was not used when entering the versions of the package in which a security problem was solved.

These are database inconsistencies, [which are requested to be solved](https://lists.debian.org/debian-security-tracker/2011/02/msg00031.html). The effect is that the affected security problems could be wrongly marked as solved in too early package versions.